# How to handle "Error in function boost::math::cyl_bessel_k<d>(d,d): numeric overflow"

Tags: c++, math, boost, error-handling, bessel-functions

I have checked the [boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/math/special_functions/bessel.hpp), and I understand that this error is the result of passing `0` as the second argument to `boost::math::cyl_bessel_k`, and it does

```
  return (v == 0) ? policies::raise_overflow_error<T>(function, 0, pol)
     : policies::raise_domain_error<T>(
     function,
     "Got x = %1%, but we need x > 0", x, pol);
```

if it receives it.

I'm 98% c++ noob.  How can this error be handled to prevent my program from crashing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the obvious answer seems to be to not pass 0, but if that is not feasible, and you are ok with the function failing, you can **catch the exception** and handle it in a way that seems right. The program wont crash then.

This [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_exceptions_handling.htm) might help explain deeper what you should do.

Comment: duh, jeez.  over here trying to make it harder than it is as usual.  thanks!